# Why is my insert into PeopleTable not working?

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to insert date into my simple table. I have 4 fields which allow nulls except for the first primarykey. It does not increment automatically so you have to add in values.

I would thought that this was simple to do but for some reason I cannot get mine to work. It seems kind of funny but it is simple and i would like to see why it is not working.

```
SELECT TOP 10 [PrimKey],[FirstNmae],[LastName],[FavoriteColor]
FROM [SQLTestDataBase].[dbo].[PeopleTable]
```

Output:

```
1   TestF       LastN       Yellow    
2   This        Yours       Red       
3   Hello       Halen       Blue
```

Insert Statement:

```
insert into PeopleTable (PrimKey, FirstNmae, LastName, FavoriteColor)
                 values (4, "TestF", "TestL", "Yellow");
```

Errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'TestF'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'TestL'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Yellow'.
```

Comment: single quotes not double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
insert into PeopleTable (PrimKey, FirstNmae, LastName, FavoriteColor)
             values (4, 'TestF', 'TestL', 'Yellow');
```

Comment: If I was building a new table how could I set the auto increment on the primary key from the GUI designer. Is there a way?

Comment: you need the `Identity Specification` under column properties.

Comment: Is that when your building the table. Because I have three columns -- Column Name, Data Type, Allow Nulls. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Well I found were you can set the primary key but it is not auto generating the key.

Comment: I found what I was looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT in SQL to add in more items.

```
        INSERT INTO table1 (A, B, C, D)
               VALUES(1, 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Above would be with no auto increment primary key.

Or you can use the GUI editor. I prefer to use the INSERT because I think that the more coding a person does the better they get at it. But that is just my own opinion. if you have a primary key set to automatically increment than you will not be able to insert the primary key.

```
        INSERT INTO table1 (ValueName)
               VALUES('My Name is Mud');
```

This is if you have a two field table and if the first field is the primary key which will auto increment then you just have to provide the values that you want to insert. In the above case there would only be one value that would be insert if the table was a two column table.